# SQL Server Slow after debugging website in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, query-performance

When I use Visual Studio 2015 to debug a website, using `file -> open website...` on my local development database, queries slows right down to the point where they take a minute or more instead of milliseconds. Similar queries run by hand using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) are slow while Visual Studio is running.

SQL Server instance is running on the same machine as Visual Studio environment.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Stop Debug mode
2. After stopping debug, kill IIS Express process
3. Disabled IntelliTrace
4. Close solution in Visual Studio

The issue still persists after the above, and *the problem is resolved  when Visual Studio is shut down or a different solution is opened.*

I checked the sql connections from SSMS and the connections were cleared once IIS Express process. It appears to be some sort of integration that Visual Studio is instrumenting with SQL Server libraries that is at the root of this.

Anybody have an idea what this might be or how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: If such is an option, does the behavior also occur in 2017/2019?

Comment: @user2864740 - No way to confirm. I don't have 2017 or later and its not on my radar. VS2015 was latest version to support clients legacy stack.

Comment: I suspect moving the DB to another Computer / VM may fix the issue.

Comment: Sadly, i have this same issue.  But i don't even have to go into debug.  Sometimes, just opening VS will bog down my SQL server (on the same machine) to a standstill.

The only way i've found to alleviate the issue is to shutdown VS or recycle SQL server service.   

This happens on VS 2015, 2017 & 2019

Comment: The issue was actually a memory related one. I ended upgrading my PC to something with a crazy amount of memory and gave the VM tons of RAM, and never saw the issue again. Would be good to know how to proactively detect the issue in SQL server. I would assume that there is some statistics buried in there that would flag memory related issues.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was memory related. If the host that runs SQL server is strained for memory, SQL server will still operate but will bog right down to the point of being essentially inoperable.

My solution was to upgrade my system so that I had a ton of RAM and gave the VM running SQL server and Visual Studio tons of ram. This has the unfortunate side effect of taking for ever to suspend the VM but at least its SQL server is usable with Visual Studio.

I still don't know how to detect by looking at SQL statistics or process monitors. I guess I may need to find/open a new question to drill into this.